# Background color of required field

Tags: html, css, required

I am using the required attribute on certain fields in a form. When form is submitted, required fields that are not filled out get the standard red border around them. Is there a way to also change the background color of the required field that is not filled out after submitting? Here is just a sample textbox that I am using with the required attribute:

```
<input id="LastName" name="LastName" type="text"  placeholder="Last Name" required/>
```

Comment: You need to look into validation....which is usually handled by Javascript

Answer (score 5):

You can use [CSS attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) like so:

```css
input[required] {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input id="LastName" name="LastName" type="text"  placeholder="Last Name"
required/>
```

This will select `input`s with `required` attributes. Now, you can apply this with some simple JavaScript to achieve the desired effect:

```js
var submit_button = document.getElementById("submit_button");

submit_button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  var required = document.querySelectorAll("input[required]");
  
  required.forEach(function(element) {
    if(element.value.trim() == "") {
      element.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    } else {
      element.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<input id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text"  placeholder="First Name" required/>
<input id="LastName" name="LastName" type="text"  placeholder="Last Name" required/>

<input id="submit_button" type="submit">
```

What this does is add an event listener when the submit button is clicked. When it is, it uses `querySelectorAll` to get all the inputs that match the CSS attribute selector, `input[required]`. Next, it does a for-each loop over the returned list of elements. Finally, it checks each inputs value, trimmed, to makes sure there's some content in there (spaces don't count). If there's nothing in the input, it sets the background color to red.

---

**Notes:**

You can tweak it as you like, make sure to cancel whatever event you are handling if the inputs are invalid, and you can add classes for styles instead of using `element.style.<style>`.

Comment: I don't think you would want that shown at all times - just after submission, like the border, which would require JavaScript.

Comment: Drew - yes that is correct, only after submission. Thanks guys.

Comment: Ahh I didn't see your update. I'll remove my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can try this by basic Css

```
:required {
 background: red;
 }
```

Or using jQuery easily it will work dynamically On button click the background color will be red hope it helps.

the html code

```
<input id="LastName" name="LastName" type="text"  placeholder="Last Name"
required/>
<input id="sub" type="button">
```

and the jquery code

```
 <script>
$('#sub').click(function(){
$('#LastName').each(function() {
if($(this).val() == '') {
$(this).css('background-color' , '#FF0000');
$(this).attr("placeholder", "Required");
 }
 });
 });
 </script>
```

But if you want to do this for an entire form then it will be something like below

```
    <script>
    $('#sub').click(function(e){ //submit button name
    e.preventDefault()
    $('.required').each(function() {   //a constant class for evert input item
    if($(this).val() == '') {
    $(this).css('background-color' , '#FF0000');
    $(this).attr("placeholder", "Required");
    }
    });
    });
    </sctript>
```

see the below fiddle
[required Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Asifuzzaman/zct8hzwu/)

must add  inside head jQuery Library

```
<head>
<script        
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">   
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: Iterating over an id for a single input? That doesn't really make much sense since you'd *hope* the id's were unique.

Comment: I just show a sample If all the inputs are in a form or div then the div Id should be there in jQuery

Comment: Asifuzzaman - I used your script for entire form. However, for html with the submit button, I said type="submit" instead of type="button". Tried both actually and neither worked. It still just has the red border around the textbox and did not change the background color after submitting.

Comment: hey I understand why you faced that see my updated last script  answer added with fiddle  for you to understand hope it helps you if not please let me know

Comment: Hi..still not working for me. Copied all code from your fiddle. Still just get red border.

Comment: i don't understand  its working in the Fiddle Did you use the jQuery Library inside the head section  ??                                                                                          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

You can change it using css as mentioned in some comments above, if it doesn't work then check whether parent background-color attribute is set, in that case you can use !important tag to enforce for the child.

Answer (score -1):

```
input[type="text"],lastname {
  background-color : red;
}
```

Comment: This would color the background of all text inputs all the time. OP only wants when the form is being validated.

Answer (score -1):

```
body input:focus:required:invalid,
body textarea:focus:required:invalid {
  color: green; 
}
```

Comment: Please include an explanation of your code and also it helps to use the code formatting and/or proper indentation for readability.