# How to require the textbox to not be empty when submitting a form?

Tags: javascript, html, validation, dom, input

So how do I require the input field in my form not to be empty when clicking on the submit button? I don't want to use the HTML attribute require. My HTML and JS code are below if someone is interested in taking a look

JS:

```
let form = document.getElementById("addForm");

// Form submit event
form.addEventListener("submit", addItem);

// Add item
function addItem(e){

e.preventDefault();
console.log(e);

// Get input value





let newItem = document.getElementById("item").value;

// Create new li
let newLI = document.createElement("li");
// Add class

newLI.className = "list-group-item";
// Add text node with input

newLI.textContent = newItem;

//Delete button

let button = document.createElement("button");
button.className = "btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right delete";
button.textContent = "X";
newLI.appendChild(button);

itemList.appendChild(newLI);
document.getElementById("item").value = "";



}
```

HTML:

```
    <form id="addForm" class="form-inline mb-3">
      <input type="text" class="form-control mr-2" id="item">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you can check if newItem is empty before preventing the submition. Like this:

```
let newItem = document.getElementById("item").value;

if(newItem === "")
{
e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work, it messes up the whole thing.

Comment: I posted it @Raffon

Comment: You need to register the event before the function like this: form.addEventListener("submit", addItem);

Comment: Yes, I have done it, but i didn't include it in the post

Comment: But what do you want todo exactly because in this code if the input is empty it will do the rest of the code if not it will just submit ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your HTML like this:

```
<form id="addForm" class="form-inline mb-3">
  <input type="text" class="form-control mr-2" id="item" required>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: But, when i use the HTML attribute required, the textbox is always red.

Comment: If this is your problem you can use this tutorial to change the css of a required element https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39808218/background-color-of-required-field

Answer (score 0):

```
function addItem(e){



//e.preventDefault();
console.log(e);

// Get input value





let newItem = document.getElementById("item").value;

if (newItem === ""){
    e.preventDefault()
}

else {
// Create new li
let newLI = document.createElement("li");
// Add class

newLI.className = "list-group-item";
// Add text node with input

newLI.textContent = newItem;

//Delete button

let button = document.createElement("button");
button.className = "btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right delete";
button.textContent = "X";
newLI.appendChild(button);

itemList.appendChild(newLI);
document.getElementById("item").value = "";
}



}
```

Comment: There you go @Raffon

Answer (score 0):

You will need to select your form input field in JavaScript -

```
const formInput = document.querySelector('#item');
```

And then in addItem function you can check something like below -

```
if (formInput.value === '') {
  console.log('No Input Entered!');
}
```